# Puzzle: Area of a square based on parallel lines going through it's corners

Tags: analytic-geometry, puzzle

Here is a little puzzle I got from my math teacher. I had a little trouble solving it; I tried to find the equations to lines by solving multiple systems, but to no avail. Could you guys please help me?

This is the given problem:
"Let WXYZ be a square. Three parallel lines d, d' and d'' pass through X, Y and Z respectively. The distance between d and d' is 5 and the distance between d and d'' is 7. What is the area of the square?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines $d,d', d''$ make an angle of $\theta$ with $XY$ , then the side length $a$, satisfies

$ a \sin(\theta) = 5 $

and

$ a \cos(\theta) = 7 $

Hence, $\tan(\theta) = \dfrac{5}{7} $

and $\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{1 }{\sqrt{ 1 + \left(\dfrac{5}{7}\right)^2 }} = \dfrac{ 7 } {\sqrt{ 74 } } $

Hence $ a = \sqrt{74} $

And the area of the square $= a^2 = 74 $